# NullReferenceException fires on SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding, bindingsource, tableadapter

I have bound a DataSet with SQL database to my project and connected it to my `dataGridView` using `dataBidningSource`, `bindingNavigator` and `tableAdapterManager`. And when I try to populate my dgv with specific data from sql table, it fires the `nullReferenceException`:

```
goodsTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from Goods where ...";
goodsTableAdapter.Fill(vxControlDataset.Goods);
```

It says, that the base of `SelectCommand` is null, though it is supposed to be `{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand}`, as I saw in other app, where this command works. 
What can be the problem with this?
If something is unclear, I do my best and try to explain it, just ask. And sorry for my English, it's not the best :)

Comment: Did you open the Connection? like `SqlConnection.Open();`

Comment: See the Docs about how you create a [SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand). The DataAdapter opens the Connection.

Comment: Yeah, and as I saw previously, you don't need to open the connection when you are using tableAdapters. Though I just tried to open it, nothing changed.

Comment: Why not just create an instance of `SqlCommand` and then assign that to the adapters select command property?

Comment: Does the query return data using SQL Server Management Studio.  You should always Test queries in SSMS before trying in c#.  The query may not be returning any data. Is the dataset Goods null (did you call the constructor  vxControlDataset.Goods = new DataSet())?  Is you connection string correct?  Doing SqlConnection.Open() will verify the connection string.  Is you default database set to the correct database?

Comment: jdweng, already checked everything you write about, except "calling vxControlDataset.Goods = new DataSet(), because first of all Goods is just a table in a DataSet, and second even if I write vxControlDataset = new DataSet it won't let me do it.

Comment: Çöđěxěŕ, using SqlCommand will for some reason  return the whole table, even though the query should return only some rows.